# Quotes regarding children

Tags: scripture

Are there any hindu quotes  in scriptures describing  the divinity of children, holiness of children or any other quote regarding children, normal children , not gods?

Comment: There are 24 gurus of Avadhuta as explained in Bhagwat Purana. 15th Guru is children. "Little boys and girls know neither honor nor dishonor. They do not nurse a grudge or a prejudice against anyone. They do not know what is their own, or what belongs to others. Their happiness springs from their own selves, their innate creativity and they do not need any external objects or conditions to be happy. I realized that the sage of perfect enlightenment is also such. A playful boy thus happened to be my fifteenth guru." https://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/24-gurus-of-dattatreya/child